# Program to make translucent grey windows to darken parts of the screen?

Tags: chrome, streaming

I use chrome with the Dark Reader extension which makes pages look darker.

However, on a website called https://courses.edx.org 
When I maximize a video on that website, large white bars result that weren't there originally before the extension

[image]

Notice how the black text on the right is surrounded by white. Previously, before installing the extension, the text was white and its surrounding was black

Yes, I could temporarily disable the extension but I plan to open other windows in the middle of my watching the video so this constant switching the extension on and off is not ideal

I don't have that problem with websites like using youtube separately from courses.edx.org

1. What are some good solutions to this?
2. What's a program that can create several grey resizable translucent windows to darken certain parts of the screen?

I'm looking for something easier to use than this that is easy for someon not great with computers and requires no coding knowledge: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView (from another stack exchange post from 3 years ago)